# Alternative to assignment operator

Tags: javascript

This is a pattern I tend to use frequently

```
const bus = this.state.channels[name] = 
            this.state.channels[name] || new EventEmitter()
```

Ideally I would like to use a Ruby like operator (which is a rejected feature request)

```
const bus = this.state.channels[name] ||= new EventEmitter()
```

The task goes like this:

1. Read an complex to reach value
2. Set a default value if uninitialized
3. Define a local variable to read several times using a shorter name

I've seen babel plugins commits supporting something like this, but they were removed.

Is it possible to do this task without code duplication?

Comment: Can you please be more specific on what this snippet should do? Is it `channels[name]` initialized lazily or is `channels` a container where every possible, even not yet accessed, key should always be resolvable to a non-null value?

Comment: Just a pointer, if after this like, `this.state.channels[name]` is set to something else, `bus` will not be updated

Comment: @bippl It is a cache container. Non yet accessed keys are initialized to a default value

Comment: @Rajesh it is totally OK. I use this pattern a lot when small functions want access to some value stored in a long / verbose path. It is intended that `bus` will only live in a much smaller (and child scope) of `this.state.channels[name]`

Answer (score 2):

There is no `||=` in JavaScript.

The first code snippet you have in your question is the shortest option available:

```
const bus = this.state.channels[name] = 
            this.state.channels[name] || new EventEmitter()
```

In other words, you're doing it right.

---

That said, if you want to shorten the assignment a bit, you could assign `this.state.channels` to a temporary variable:

```
const channels = this.state.channels;
const bus = channels[name] = channels[name] || new EventEmitter()
```

Comment: Since the `||=` is not a legal operator I wanted to know if there is a less verbose alternative to what I can do now. Well, my question is now at -3 so it must be a useless problem :(

Comment: BTW. The first version has 101 characters, the second one 104

Comment: Your question is only at `-1`. You could reduce the character count by changing the temporary variable's name.

Comment: @SystematicFrank you should not be concerned with number of characters. If you use any bundling tool like `webpack`, `grunt` or `gulp`, they will take care of it. You should rather focus on writing readable code.

Comment: If I was writing it, I would rather use `if (... === undefined) { ... }`. For less typing, I would use second suggestion in above answer. This will ensure by variable always have latest value. You can read my comment under question for more info.

Comment: @Rajesh I don't care for the characters bundled into my code, I just care for the amount of characters my eyes must see and code I must duplicate. My care for readable code is shown in that I nest state related variables into "this.state". Actually I have tons of naming conventions that makes my code very verbose because I insist in making state / cache / setup / actions / multiple-constructors very explicit. My question is about avoiding the negative side of wanting more readable code.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it like that but it is still 2 steps :

```
const bus = this.state.channels[name] || new EventEmitter();
this.state.channels[name] = bus;
```